# Не удается установить драйвера Nvidia

Tags: linux, nvidia, opensuse

Не удается поставить драйвера nvidia на дистрибутив opensuse tumbleweed. Модель ноутбука Asus TUF GAMING 505DD. CPU ryzen 5, GPU nvidia 1050. Как я понял bumblebee не работает с процессорами AMD и выдавал такую ошибку при проверке статуса bumblebee:

```
[509.786919] [INFO] No Intel video card found, testing for dual-nvidia system. [509.786979] [ERROR] No integrated video card found, quitting.
```

При попытке что либо запустить выдавало ошибку что не запущен демон bumblebee.
Сейчас установлены драйвера x11-video-nvidiaG05.

```
kokos@localhost:~> sudo zypper se -i nvidia
Загрузка данных о репозиториях...
Чтение установленных пакетов...

С  | Имя                       | Заключение                                                            | Тип
---+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+------
i+ | kernel-firmware-nvidia    | Kernel firmware files for Nvidia Tegra and graphics drivers           | пакет
i+ | libnvidia-container-tools | NVIDIA container runtime library (command-line tools)                 | пакет
i+ | libnvidia-container1      | NVIDIA container runtime library                                      | пакет
i  | nvidia-computeG05         | NVIDIA driver for computing with GPGPU                                | пакет
i  | nvidia-gfxG05-kmp-default | NVIDIA graphics driver kernel module for GeForce 600 series and newer | пакет
i  | nvidia-glG05              | NVIDIA OpenGL libraries for OpenGL acceleration                       | пакет
i+ | pcp-pmda-nvidia-gpu       | Performance Co-Pilot (PCP) metrics for the Nvidia GPU                 | пакет
i+ | x11-video-nvidiaG05       | NVIDIA graphics driver for GeForce 600 series and newer               | пакет
```

Так же nvidia драйвер не определяется для карточки.

```
  kokos@localhost:~> inxi -xxx -G
    Graphics:
      Device-1: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 3 GB Max-Q] vendor: ASUSTeK 
      driver: N/A bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 10de:1c91 
      Device-2: AMD Picasso vendor: ASUSTeK driver: amdgpu v: kernel 
      bus ID: 05:00.0 chip ID: 1002:15d8 
      Device-3: IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
      bus ID: 3-1:2 chip ID: 13d3:56a2 serial: 0x0001 
      Display: x11 server: X.org 1.20.9 compositor: gnome-shell v: 3.36.7 
      driver: amdgpu,ati unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa 
      resolution: <xdpyinfo missing> 
      OpenGL: renderer: AMD RAVEN (DRM 3.39.0 5.9.10-1-default LLVM 11.0.0) 
      v: 4.6 Mesa 20.2.3 direct render: Yes
```

Так же вывод lspci.

```
sudo lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 3 GB Max-Q] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 18f1
    Kernel modules: nouveau
--
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 18f1
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
```

При установки с офф. пакета выдает следующею ошибку.

```
Your kernel headers for kernel 5.9.10-1-default cannot be found at                                                                                                                                                                  
         /lib/modules/5.9.10-1-default/build or /lib/modules/5.9.10-1-default/source.
```

Comment: самое главное : удалить **nouveau** !

Comment: он у меня в черном списке добавлен этого не достаточно получается ?

Comment: пакет linux-headers поставь версии 5.9.10